# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0, Yet JSON Always Reads As Valid

Tags: node.js, json

I'm trying to load a JSON file, which is showing up perfect for all validators. I've even gone in and tried to edit the hex file, which did nothing to help. No matter what I do, the file won't parse. Here is my code and my file.

```
fs.readFile("./Docs/" + foldNum +".json", "utf8", (err, jsonString) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error reading file from disk:", err);
            return;
        }
        try {
            console.log(jsonString)
            jsonString = jsonString.split("").filter(char => char.codePointAt(0)).join("")
            const doc = JSON.parse(jsonString);
            console.log("doc id is:", doc); 
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error parsing JSON string:", err);
        }
    });
```

```
[{"doc_id":"cnn-test-fbbafa743a8c2ecd2cedf65c6c61956b2db8ec5c"},{"doc_id":"dm-test-0f0789390d67698283cc87b2e046b5c5cd77edb7"},{"doc_id":"dm-test-207df192edc1836250b69d1bc5b9e6a38206eb78"},{"doc_id":"dm-test-051db270afc32571a08c15124330efe89d80fea8"},{"doc_id":"dm-test-8764fb95bfad8ee849274873a92fb8d6b400eee2"}]
```

As you can see in my code, I've tried removing null characters, to no avail. The file certainly exists, it shows the full content of the file on the console.log line and it looks absolutely fine. What in the world is going on?